# Python how to download a file from s3 and then reuse

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

how can I download a file from s3 and then reuse instead of keeping downloading it everytime when the endpoint is called?

```
    @app.route("/get", methods=['GET'])
    def get():
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        ids = pickle.loads(s3.Bucket('bucket').Object('file').get()['Body'].read())
        ...
```

Comment: Store it in your local filesystem?

Comment: the file is 16gb and need to be updated daily

Comment: This files are for web aplication? Ppl download it from your website?

Comment: these are corpus and embedding files from training an ai model, the app is a search

Comment: Then maybe EFS, instead of S3 would be better. EFS is regular filesystem, so you can read and write to the files directly in EFS, unlike with S3. No need to download them first.

Comment: great, thanks will look into that

Comment: No problem. If you like, I can provide answer with extra info and links?

Comment: that would be super helpful, appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

Since the files are large (16GB) and need to be read and updated often, instead of S3, an [EFS filesystem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/whatisefs.html) could be used for their storage:

> Amazon Elastic File System (Amazon EFS) provides a simple, serverless, set-and-forget **elastic file system** for use with AWS Cloud services and on-premises resources.

EFS provides NFS filesystems that you can [mount](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs.html) to your instance, or even multiple instances at the same time. You can also mount the same filesystem to ECS containers and lambda functions.

Since EFS provides regular filesystem, you can **write and read the files directly** in it. There is no need to copy it first as in S3 which is object storage (not filesystem).

Its worth pointing out, that convenience of [EFS costs](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/pricing/) more then using S3. However, now you can reduce the cost of using EFS, if this is a problem, by using just released [Amazon EFS One Zone storage class](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-lower-cost-one-zone-storage-classes-for-amazon-elastic-file-system/).

Comment: @Kelvin How did it go?